# preg_replace errors on special characters

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace

I want to change the following as below:
% => \%
_  => \_
\   => \\

E.g:

```
1. ali% sdn bhd -> ali\% sdn bhd
2. ali_ sdn bhd -> ali\_ sdn bhd
3. ali\ sdn bhd -> ali\\ sdn bhd
```

And here is the code written:

```
<?php
$special_characters = array("%","_","\\");
$replace_special_characters = array("\\%","\\_","\\\\\\\\");

foreach($special_characters as $value)
{   
        if(strpos($companyname, $value) !== FALSE)
        {
            $companyname = preg_replace('/'.$value.'/', $replace_special_characters, $companyname);   //ERROR HERE
        }   
}
?>
```

However, from above output, I get this error:

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array ...
```

Which part did I write wrong? How should I modify it?

Comment: maybe I miss something obvious here, but isn't this covered already by the function str_replace? http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't replace a `string` by an `array`using preg_replace.

You have to get position of your element in your array and then get replacement using this position:

```
<?php
$special_characters = array("%","_","\\");
$replace_special_characters = array("\\%","\\_","\\\\\\\\");

$i = 0; //set the original position
foreach($special_characters as $value)
{   
        if(strpos($companyname, $value) !== FALSE)
        {
            echo '/'.$value.'/';
            $companyname = preg_replace('/'.$value.'/', $replace_special_characters[$i], $companyname);   //Here you get replacement using the current position, so a string is set as replacement, not an array
        }   
        $i++;//after each value, you increment the position
}
?>
```

I'm not sure if this code works but it shows you the logic you need to implement.

Comment: this cannot works, another error on the same line:  preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '/' found ...

Comment: As I said this is not guaranteed to work, the goal here is to make you understand what is your error. I think you should add some debug before preg_replace to know which $value you are currently looking for. I updated example to show you how

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)?

```
$string = 'ali% sdn bhd ali_ sdn bhd  ali\ sdn bhd';
$res = str_replace(array("\\","%","_"), array("\\\\","\\%","\\_"), $string);
echo $res,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
ali\% sdn bhd ali\_ sdn bhd  ali\\ sdn bhd
```

From the documentation:

> **Caution Replacement order gotcha**
>
> Because str_replace() replaces left to right, it might replace a
>   previously inserted value when doing multiple replacements. See also
>   the examples in this document.